# Burn .ass subtitle onto .webm with no loss of quality

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I'm trying to burn .ass subtitles onto a .webm, using  `ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf ass=subtitles.ass output.webm`  but it shrinks from like 150MB to 9MB.   How do I add the subtitles without losing quality ?

Comment: Do you want to mux the subtitles or burn them?

Comment: Burn -- based on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf ass=subtitles.ass -b:v 0 -crf 20 output.webm
```

The libvpx encoders for WebM, by default, perform Constrained Quality encoding, and use the bitrate as a ceiling. Default bitrate is 200 kbps. To remove bitrate ceiling, set bitrate to 0. `-crf` controls the [quality level](https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/bitrate-modes/).

Comment: Cheers!  Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Jon, so why you don't accept this answer? Click on check mark near it.